# NodeJS + MongoDB - simplifying functions

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am learning nodejs + mongodb. I do not want to use `mongoose` as of now. 
I have below functions which work fine. However, my question is how to further simply this? both functions look same except the highlighted `***` statement.

```
//for returning records

var resultsQuery = function(search, select, callback) {
    mongo.connect(mongoURL, function(err, db) {
        if (err){ throw err; }
      ***  db.collection("coll").find(search, select).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            callback(result);
            db.close();
        });
    });
};

// for updating records 

var resultsUpdate = function(filter, set, callback) {
    mongo.connect(mongoURL, function(err, db) {
        if (err){ throw err; }
       *** db.collection("coll").update(filter, set, function(err, result) {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            callback(result);
            db.close();
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the common things in one function and pass in the callback:

```
var resultsQuery = function(search, select, callback) {
    xpto(callback, (db, cb) => db.collection("coll").find(search, select).toArray(cb))
};

// for updating records 
var resultsUpdate = function(filter, set, callback) {
    xpto(callback, (db, cb) =>  db.collection("coll").update(filter, set, cb))
};

function xpto(callback, op) {
   mongo.connect(mongoURL, function(err, db) {
        if (err){ throw err; }
          op(db, function(err, result) {
            if (err) { throw err; }
            callback(result);
            db.close();
        });
    });
}
```

There are different ways to do this, but I think this illustrates the idea.